# Marquee carousel split up in two different row instead of one (cargo collective)

Tags: html, css, carousel, marquee

As I said I'm building this marquee carousel but the images, instead of one row split up in two.

```
.marquee {
    color: black!important;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

 <div class="marquee" speed="-10">
     <div grid-row="" grid-pad="0" grid-gutter="0">
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 1}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 2}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 3}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 4}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 5}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 6}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 7}</div>
    <div grid-col="x9" grid-pad="0">{image 8}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant CSS. Where are grid settings?

Comment: Cargo collective kinda hide this! Here's the link to the page:
https://civitonia.cargo.site/27996549

Comment: Are you saying you can't see the relevant CSS in your browser's dev tools inspect facility?